# Is there a way to use GCC __attribute__((noreturn)) and <stdnoreturn.h> sanely in a single translation unit?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c11

In C11, there is the keyword `_Noreturn` which is a function specifier (like `inline` is) that indicates the function does not return — it calls `exit()` or equivalent.  There is also a header, `<stdnoreturn.h>`, the complete definition for which is:

> #### 7.23 `_Noreturn <stdnoreturn.h>`
>
> ¶1 The header `<stdnoreturn.h>` defines the macro
>
> ```
> noreturn
> ```
>
> which expands to `_Noreturn`.

In GNU C (GCC), there is an attribute `__attribute__((noreturn))` that does essentially the same job.  One difference is that `__attribute__((noreturn))` can appear before or after the function declarator:

```
extern __attribute__((noreturn)) void err_error(const char *format, ...);
extern void err_error(const char *format, ...) __attribute__((noreturn));
```

The problem is that if you include `<stdnoreturn.h>` in a translation unit (TU), any subsequent uses of `__attribute__((noreturn))` get mapped to `__attribute__((_Noreturn))` which then causes the compilation to fail because the attribute `_Noreturn` is not recognized (even though the keyword is recognized as a keyword).  That is, as far as I can tell, you cannot use both systems at once.

- Is there any way around this problem other than either:

  1. a big-bang migration of all code using the attribute to use `<stdnoreturn.h>`, or
  2. using the less-than-entirely-graceful `_Noreturn` keyword?

You can detect C11 by testing `__STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L` — the value was specified by Technical Corrigendum 1 because the standard accidentally left the value incompletely specified:

> `__STDC_VERSION__` The integer constant *201ymmL*.<sup>178)</sup>
>
> <sup>178)</sup> This macro was not specified in ISO/IEC 9899:1990 and was specified as 199409L in
>   ISO/IEC 9899:1990/Amd.1:1995 and as 199901L in ISO/IEC 9899:1999. The intention is that this
>   will remain an integer constant of type `long int` that is increased with each revision of this
>   International Standard.

This can be used to condition the treatment in any one header file, but if you have a mixture of modified and unmodified (C11 and C99) headers, I seem to be running into intractable problems with `<stdnoreturn.h>`.

- Is it worth filing a bug with GCC to request that `__attribute__((_Noreturn))` be made into a synonym for `__attribute__((noreturn))` — which would resolve the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `__attribute__((__noreturn__))`, instead.

All the gcc attributes have a `__` version such that you can sanely use them in system headers without polluting the user name space.

Some platform providers also don't seem to be aware of that problem. I recently discovered that for OS X they have the unprotected version in a macro `__dead2`.

Also you can't detect the C standard version reliably with the `__STDC_VERSION__` macro. All the gcc and clang versions that have a "test" version for C11 that claims C11 if called with `-std=c11` without completely implementing it fully. The newer versions are almost there, but only almost.

Comment: Ahah — this looks promising.  The manual reference appears to be [Function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes), which does mention the extra double underscores, but I'd managed to miss that on previous occasions when I'd looked.

Comment: Is this compatible with clang?

Comment: @user129393192 yes, it should be compatible with clang. But notice that this is an ancient question and a an ancient answer. If you have the chance you should switch to modern C and use standard attributes. C23 has `[[noreturn]]`, `[[_Noreturn]]`, `[[__noreturn__]]` and `[[___Noreturn__]]` and they all do the same thing.