# _Noreturn in a struct in c: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '_Noreturn'

Tags: c, gcc, c11, noreturn

I am trying to compile a piece of code that contains _Noreturn:

```
#ifndef SOMEHEADER_H
#define SOMEHEADER_H

#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern struct s {

    _Noreturn void (*somenoreturnfunc)(bool);
} svar;

#endif
```

Which gives me:

`error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '_Noreturn'` on:
`_Noreturn void (*somenoreturnfunc)(bool);`

So I tried the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552467/is-there-a-way-to-use-gcc-attribute-noreturn-and-stdnoreturn-h-sanely-i):

```
#ifndef SOMEHEADER_H
#define SOMEHEADER_H

#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "noreturn.h"

extern struct s {

    noreturn void (*somenoreturnfunc)(bool);
} svar;

#endif
```

noreturn.h:

```
#ifndef NO_RETURN_H
#define NO_RETURN_H
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
#define noreturn _Noreturn
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#define noreturn __attribute__((noreturn))
#else
#define noreturn
#endif
#endif
```

But the error still happens:

```
In file included from ../include/someinclude.h:8:0,
                 from src/main.c:17:
../include/noreturn.h:4:18: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '_Noreturn'
 #define noreturn _Noreturn
                  ^
../include/someinclude.h:19:5: note: in expansion of macro 'noreturn'
     noreturn void (*somenoreturnfunc)(bool);
     ^
```

I am baffled because it is compiled with c11 so it should work:

```
make V=1
cc src/main.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic -ffreestanding -static -I../libopencm3/include -I../include -DSTM32F1 -g -DDEBUG -DBUILD_STYLE=\"DEBUG\" -O0 -Iinclude -I../librt/include  -MMD -MT build/main.o -MF build/main.d -o build/main.o -c src/main.c
In file included...
```

GCC version is 5.4.1:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (15:5.4.1+svn241155-1) 5.4.1 20160919
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

which should support all C11 features (_Noreturn is supported [since 4.7](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status)).

What am I doing wrong and how could I resolve this error?

--
Edit: Maybe a self contained example can help:

main.c:

```
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct s {

    _Noreturn void (*somenoreturnfunc)(bool);
} svar;

int main()
{
        svar.somenoreturnfunc = 0;
        return 0;
}
```

Compiling this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic -ffreestanding -static -DSTM32F1 -g -DDEBUG -DBUILD_STYLE=\"DEBUG\" -O0 -MMD -MT main.o -MF main.d -o main.o -c main.c
main.c:7:5: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '_Noreturn'
     _Noreturn void (*somenoreturnfunc)(bool);
     ^
main.c:5:8: warning: struct has no members [-Wpedantic]
 struct s {
        ^
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:12:6: error: 'struct s' has no member named 'somenoreturnfunc'
  svar.somenoreturnfunc = 0;
      ^
```

Yet when compiling with the same command line and removing `_Noreturn` the compilation succeeds.

This also happens when compiling with
`gcc -std=c11 -o main main.c`:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -o main main.c
main.c:7:5: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘_Noreturn’
     _Noreturn void (*somenoreturnfunc)(bool);
     ^~~~~~~~~
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:12:6: error: ‘struct s’ has no member named ‘somenoreturnfunc’
  svar.somenoreturnfunc = 0;
      ^
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: In this specific case the function really never returns to the caller so there should be no UB. Thank you for the link, it does give me some extra info. Maybe another option (not preferable) would be to remove all `_Noreturn` keywords but then C shouldn't have added it in the first place, right?

Comment: @Clonk That question is about an attribute, not the standard function specifier. Actually a non-`void` `_Noreturn` function does not make sense.

Comment: A workaround is to use a typedef as in: `typedef _Noreturn void (*somenoreturnfunctype)(bool);
struct s {

    somenoreturnfunctype somenoreturnfunc;
} svar;`

Comment: @Frankie_C it does indeed compile but leaves a warning `typedef '..' declared '_Noreturn'`, does this mean that _Noreturn is discarded  from the typedef or is it just a heads up to the developer meaning 'Hey maybe you don't mean this'?

Comment: @Frankie_C `typedef _Noreturn void (*somenoreturnfunctype)(bool);` is incorrect in ISO C

Comment: Typedefs, opposed to the function pointer specification, accept function specifiers, even if they have no effect. That's not an error, but the specifier is ignored (you should get this warning 'specifier ignored'). The real point is that the _Noreturn qualification makes no sense when creating a pointer to a function.

Comment: @Frankie_C You are wrong,  it is clearly specified in section 6.7.4/2  of the Standard that they do not (as explained in the answers below)

Comment: @M.M The standard says in the section about function specifiers that the **shall be used only in declaration of identifiers of functions**. But no direct prohibition is made in typedef constraints. So almost all compilers, maybe precautionally,  don't flag an error, but warns about, and the specifier is ignored. I haven't met yet a compiler that behaves differently.

Comment: @Frankie_C "shall be used only in X" means that it is prohibited in any cases other than X

Comment: @M.M I agree with you, the standard is clear in function declaration semantic. What I point out is that anyway compilers tolerate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ISO C, `_Noreturn` cannot be used on the declaration of a function pointer.  It can only be used on the declaration of a function. (Ref: C11 6.7.4/2).

You will have to abandon this idea.  The function specifiers (`inline` and `_Noreturn`) are not part of a function's type.

There is another problem in your code: you define `svar` in the header, this will cause an ODR violation if the header is included in two or more translation units. It should only have a declaration in the header, and a definition in one unit.

---

To call through the function pointer and retain `_Noreturn` semantics , perhaps you could make a shim, e.g.:

```
inline _Noreturn void call_somefunc( struct s *ps, bool b )
{
    ps->somenoreturnfunc(b);
}
```

but there is no way to have the compiler enforce that when you assign to the function pointer, it is actually a `_Noreturn` function.

Comment: Ah didn't know that it couldn't be used like that!

Comment: That would add just another indirection without any benefit/"type"safety. I don't doubt what you wrote (now), but the initial idea of `_Noreturn` was to allow the caller to optimise its code (e.g. saving registers before/cleanup after, etc.) around the call. Not allowing the specifier for pointers makes this much less useful. Seems like the C standard needs a major overhaul not only structural, but also wrt. grouping type "modifiers".

Comment: @toohonestforthissite the main idea of `_Noreturn` is to allow the compiler to optimize; which it can do if my function is used.  I agree that they could look into making it a part of the function's type (and therefore, usable in a function pointer etc.)

Comment: @M.M: I think the main problem is they tgry to fit all newer features into the old, legacy cathegories. It didn't work well for `typedef` already and becomes more and more problematic. It would have been good they had taken the time without adding new features to resolve all these "flaws", but if I understand it right, nothing much has changed.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite, no the problem here is backwards compatibility, I think. If you want to be able to add annotations like this to existing interfaces, eg `exit`, you don't want them to conflict with other declarations that user code may already have laying around. API changes in C library interfaces are quite difficult to handle.

Comment: @JensGustedt: How could a new keyword change existing APIs which can't have used it apparently? And now, allowing it for function pointers also does not change them, because they also could not have used it for them. No, C has an increasing problem with inconsistencies by the inflexible semanitc of type/identifier "modifiers". which don't really fit into the "specifier"/"qualifier"/… scheme. It's a problem of the complexity. Finally: breaking the compatibility with legacy code is a high time in some places. There are precedences: VLAs/FAMs, `x % y`, etc.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite: A major problem the C Standards have always had is that they favor simplicity of description over usefulness of semantics.  None of the compilers I've used that predated C89 had any trouble parsing `0x1E-1` as equivalent to `0x1E -1` (with a white space between the `E` and the `1` ), but C89 demands that compilers treat 0x1E-1 as one pp-number token, and thus disallow its use within expressions, because that makes the description of pp-number slightly easier.  If a construct would have useful meaning and can be easily supported it, forbidding merely to simplify...

Comment: ...a description of the language puts the cart before the horse.  Another issue is that the Standard fails to recognize that certain *concepts* are useful in many implementations, even if the details vary.  For example, while many systems use have a uniform address space and a single calling convention, but many others could benefit from a syntax to indicate that an object, function, or pointer target should be placed in an address space designated by an target-platform-dependent string, or that a function should be called in a way likewise designated.  If three vendors each produce...

Comment: ...an implementation for a particular target platform that documents various named address spaces or conventions, having the Standard specify a syntax for supplying the strings, but letting the implementation specify the meaning (typically adopting the same meaning as the platform) would avoid the need for programmers to manually accommodate every vendor/platform combination.

Answer (score 2):

The function specifiers `_Noreturn` and `inline` are not part of the type of a function, they are part of the declaration. And the C17 standard states in 6.7.4 that function specifiers "shall be used only in the declaration of an identifier for a function." This means they cannot be used in the in the declaration of a *pointer* to a function.

So unfortunately this is not possible; a typedef won't help either.

Comment: C17 is still not standard (and the question explicitly mentions it's using C11). Standard is C11, so we have to look this up. C11 does not state anything against the usage of this specifier. I agree, for `inline` it does not make sense to declare a pointer, simply because it's contrary to what `inline` implies. But for `_Noreturn` it can make sense for the calle to optimise the code (that's what it was added for, e.g. omitting the jump over an `else` branch)  Strange behaviour.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite C17 is standard, [you can buy it from ISO](https://www.iso.org/standard/74528.html). Also, this is difficult to figure out, but C11 6.7.4 is the C11 equivalent of C17 6.7.4. (And the text is the same in both)

Comment: @M.M: Thanks, I wasn't aware it exiss. Ok, from what I now read, it does not include new/different features, but only corections/fixes to C11. That makes me wonder even more why they didn't change this in C17 for `_Noreturn`. From my view it's exactly to tell the caller it can do optimisations around the call and that's valid for direct calls as well as via pointers (i.e. pointer declarations). To me it seem `_Noreturn` still has to make it's way properly into the language;  right now it's more of hack to treat it the same as `inline`. …

Comment: @M.M … Or they just forgot about function pointers (not the first obvious and long-term defect, see `volatile`). Looks like the "calssic" cathegories `specifier`, etc. are not sufficient anymore; `typedef` is another example.

Answer (score 0):

Many good answers already, but for clarity I would like to ad the following:

From C11, 6.7.4.9:

> The implementation should produce a diagnostic message for a function declared with a _Noreturn function specifier that appears to be capable of returning to its caller.

So _Noreturn has the purpose of informing the compiler to check there is no control path in the function declared as _Noreturn where it actually returns.

Knowing this, it is now clear why you cannot declare a function pointer to be _Noreturn because the compiler cannot check the return semantics of the function assigned.

(Of course, a compiler could see _Noreturn as part of the type and then check that only _Noreturn functions are assigned to the function pointer. The current definition in the standard seems a bit useless to me.)

Comment: 1) It's not a requirement (that would be "shall", not "should". Likely because an implementation can't always detect if a function returns or not (halting problem). 2) `_Noreturn` has the purpose to allow the caller do optimisations around the call. 3) Yes, that's a defect in that standard steming from the legacy cathegories wnd not having well thought about this particular keyword. It's because `_Noreturn` as well as `inline` don't apply to the function (type), but the identifier, i.e. name. 4) No, a compiler cannot see it as part of the type, because that would make it non-compliant.